# Isolation forest results every value -1

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pandas, outlier

I am trying out isolation forest to detect outliers in a specific target column of my dataset. The dataset contains 188 rows of data with 178 rows with the same value for that target column and the isolation forest gives out every single value -1. Is that a bug or should I take it as that the values are fine? Here is a piece of the code. (I know I need to stop using `ix`).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest

df1 = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/smotapar/Desktop/ase/source/data.csv')
clf = IsolationForest(n_estimators=200, random_state=10, bootstrap=False)
clf.fit(df1.ix[:,"target"].values.reshape(-1, 1))
clf.predict(df1.ix[:,"target"].values.reshape(-1, 1))
```

Which gives out an output:

> array([-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1])

So, what did I do wrong? If I didn't, why is the output like this?

Comment: What's your dataset?

Comment: Just send your dataset here. I will try.